# Consider the following functional dependencies, Find a minimal cover

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

consider a relation schema with attributes ABCGWXYZ and the set of dependencies

```
F{XZ-ZYB, YA-CG, C-W, B-G, XZ-G}
```

solve the following problems using the appropriate algorithms

A: find the minimal cover for f

what i find is:

```
XZ-Y
XZ-B
XZ-G
YA-C
YA-G
C-W
B-G
```

pretty much everything in the f, but the solution says, XZ-G is redundant. Can anyone explain to me ?

B: is the dependency XZA-YB implied by f?

I just feel like the it ask is weird, i don't know how to answer ?

Comment: What are the keys? How do you derive F->A from your minimal cover?

Comment: This is actually the whole question, it dosen't have anything else

Comment: I am going to change the question to something similar, it's the same topic, i wish you can help me

Comment: Deriving the keys is part of your job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the solution says, XZ-G is redundant. Can anyone explain to me ?

```
XZ->B
 B->G
```